# Functional Equation Solution?

Tags: functional-equations, substitution

I've been trying to solve this:

$f: \Bbb{R\setminus \{1\} \to \Bbb{R}}, f(2-x) + x f(\frac{1}{1-x}) = 3-x $

Seems sensible to simplify slightly by replacing $x$ with $(2-x)$ to give:

$f(x) + (2-x)f(\frac{1}{x-1}) = x+1$

I'm assuming I need to use substitution(s) from here, but I'm embarrassingly rusty at maths these days, and I haven't been able to crack this one. I'm hoping someone will be able to come up with a quick solution and put me out of my misery...

Thank you.

Comment: $x\mapsto\frac{1}{x-1}$ generates an infinite group.  I think something is wrong with the initial question, maybe with $f(\frac{1}{x-1})$ instead of $f(\frac{1}{1-x})$?

Comment: Ahhhhh. Thank you. I'm not going crazy then! Hmmm. Yeah, I can't be 100% sure that the original question is correct (and I've long since forgotten where I saw it) :-(